# Browser doesn't show expected certificate error

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, internet-explorer, browser, certificate

Normally, most of the machines get error when opening url https://host:port/app/xx.do

- IE: The security certificate presented by thi swebsite was issued for a different website's address
- Chrome: Your connection is not private -- There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID)

After clicking "Continue"/"Process", it is expected to

- IE: Load every dependency including the jar
- Chrome: A popup error says: The xxx has not been initialized!

However, there is one machine, it doesn't get the certificate error in both browsers, nor the jar initialized error in Chrome.
When trying to test the web through IE, surely it failed without any warning messages.

## So, how can we get the certificate warning back? And let the IE load that jar as normal.

Comment: Can you please inform us, how that site was hosted? Is it hosted on IIS? Is that machine connected with your network? which OS is installed on that machine? Try to reset the IE with default settings and try to check whether it solves your issue or not. Also try to install the latest windows updates and check whether it solves the issue or not.

Comment: Thanks @Deepak-MSFT . The network is fine. We are also suggested to rebuild the OS by the support from the real life for the IE. However, we prefer to locate the root cause and try to fix it.

Comment: Without specific information about site and OS we are not able to find the issue. You can try to provide above asked information. It can help to narrow down the issue. Did you tried to reset the IE? You can have a try and let us know about your testing result.